# Is the order of evaluation defined by a specification for JavaScripts in a page

Tags: javascript

If I include two scripts like so (one directly in the page, one in a remote resource):

```
<!-- ... -->

<script>
 console.log('foo');
</script>

<script src="bar.js"></script>

<!-- ... -->
```

Is the order of evaluation guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, it is. The browser parses and executes top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are executed in the order they appear on the page. An exception is if an external Javascript has the `async` attribute. This will be loaded in the background, and executed when the response arrives.